# entire program not executing

Tags: python, io

I have a program that interfaces with another program to process data. The program I have written has three main parts (separated by lines of ### below). When I run the entire program, it does not work (specifically the second subprocess call doesn't execute and produce a summary file for which the third part of the program is responsible for dealing with). However, whenever I break them into three separate programs and run them in the terminal, everything is fine. Any tips or suggestions as to how to get this to run as one program?

```
#### part 1:
import glob
import subprocess
import os
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
import re
import ntpath

x = open('data.txt', 'w')
m = open('graphing_data.txt', 'w')

ckopuspath= '/Volumes/DAVIS/sfit-ckopus/ckopus'
command_init = 'sfit4Layer0.py -bv5 -fh'
subprocess.call(command_init.split(), shell=False)

for line in open('sfit4.ctl', 'r'): # write in later specific directory line
    p = line.strip()
    if p.startswith('band.1.nu_start'):
        a,b = p.split('=')
        b = float(b)
        b = "{0:.3f}".format(b)
        lowwav = b
        lowwav = float(lowwav)
    if p.startswith('band.1.nu_stop'):
        a,b = p.split('=')
        b = float(b)
        b = "{0:.3f}".format(b)
        highwav = b 
        highwav = float(highwav)

with open('/Volumes/DAVIS/calpy_em27_neu/spectra_out_demo/info.txt', 'rt') as infofile: # the info.txt file created by CALPY
    for count, line in enumerate(infofile):
        with open('t15asc.4', 'w') as t:
            lat = re.search('Latitude of location:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
            lat = lat.split()
            lat = lat[3]
            lat = float(lat)

            lon = re.search('Longitude of location:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
            lon = lon.split()
            lon = lon[3]
            lon = float(lon)

            date = re.search('Time of measurement \(UTC\): ([^;]+)', line).group(0) 
            date = date.split()

            yeardate = date[4]
            yeardate = yeardate.split('-')
            year = int(yeardate[0])
            month = int(yeardate[1])
            day = int(yeardate[2])

            time = date[5]    
            time = time.split(':')
            hour = int(time[0])
            minute = int(time[1])
            second = time[2]
            second = second.split('.')
            second = int(second[0])   

            dur = re.search('Duration of measurement \[s\]: ([^;]+)', line).group(0)
            dur = dur.split()
            dur = float(dur[4])

            numpoints = re.search('Number of values of one scan:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
            numpoints = numpoints.split()
            numpoints = float(numpoints[6])

            fov = re.search('semi FOV \[rad\] :\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
            fov = fov.split()
            fov = fov[3]
            fov = float(fov[1:])

            sza = re.search('sun Azimuth \[deg\]:\s*([^;]+)', line, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
            sza = sza.split()
            sza = float(sza[3])

            snr = 0.0000
            roe = 6396.2
            res = 0.5000

            calpy_path = '/Volumes/DAVIS/calpy_em27_neu/spectra_out_demo/140803/*' # the CALPY output files!
            files1 = glob.glob(calpy_path)
            with open(files1[count], 'r') as g:
                ints = []
                ints_count = 0
                for line in g:
                    wave_no, intensity = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
                    if lowwav <= wave_no <= highwav:
                        ints.append(str(intensity))
                        ints_count = ints_count + 1

            spacebw = (highwav - lowwav)/ ints_count          

            d = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
            t.write('{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}{:>12.5f}'.format(sza,roe,lat,lon,snr)) # line 1
            t.write("\n")
            t.write('{:>10d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}{:>5d}'.format(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)) # line 2
            t.write("\n")
            t.write( ('{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)) + "UT Solar Azimuth:" + ('{:>6.3f}'.format(sza)) + " Resolution:" + ('{:>6.4f}'.format(res)) + " Duration:" + ('{:>6.2f}'.format(dur))) # line 3
            t.write("\n")
            t.write('{:>22.12f}{:>22.12f}{:>22.12e}{:>15d}'.format(lowwav,highwav,spacebw,ints_count)) # line 4
            t.write("\n")
            t.write('\n'.join(map(str, ints)) + '\n')   

######################################## part 2:                    

            command_two = 'sfit4Layer0.py -bv5 -fs'

            subprocess.call(command_two.split(), shell=False)  #writes the summary file

######################################## part 3

            infile = '/Volumes/DAVIS/calpy_em27_neu/spectra_out_demo/summary' 
            lines = open(infile, 'r').readlines()
            line_number = 0
            line4= lines[line_number + 3]
            variables = line4.split(" ")
            sample = variables[1]
            time = variables[2]
            Z = variables[3]
            A = variables[4]
            D = variables[5]
            R = variables[6]
            P = variables[7]
            V = variables[8]
            E = variables[9]
            x.write('{0} {1} {2} {3} '.format(sample, time, Z, A))
            time = time[:-2]
            numofgas = lines[line_number + 5]
            numofgas = int(numofgas.strip())
            x.write(str(numofgas))
            count2 = 0

            while count2 < numofgas:
                gasinfo = lines[line_number + 7 + count2]
                data = gasinfo.split()
                gasnum = data[0]
                gasname = data[1]
                IFPRF = data[2]
                apprcol = data[3]
                retcol = data[4]
                x.write('     {0} {1}'.format(gasname, retcol))
                m.write('{0},{1}\n'.format(time, retcol))
                count2 = count2 + 1

            line17 = lines[line_number + 10 + count2]
            print(numofgas)
            params = line17.split()
            bandstart = params[1]
            bandstop = params[2]
            space = params[3]
            nptsb = params[4]
            pmax = params[5]
            fovdia = params[6]
            meansnr = params[7]
            x.write(' {0} {1} {2} {3} '.format(bandstart, bandstop, nptsb, meansnr))

            line21 = lines[line_number + 14 + count2]
            info = line21.split()
            fitrms = info[0]
            chi2 = info[1]
            dofsall = info[2]
            dofstrg = info[3]
            iter = info[4]
            maxxiter = info[5]
            x.write('{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(fitrms, chi2, dofsall, dofstrg, iter))
            x.write('\n')

x.close()
m.close()
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages/other debug info? Are you sure it's a python problem? Also is the part after `subprocess.call` in part 1 executed for sure? Notice how `call()` waits for the newly spawned process to exit, so it could just be "pausing" there.

Comment: I know that the first subprocess.call is executed for sure (the information appears in the terminal window). Basically the error message I get is associated with Part 2 - that subprocess.call is supposed to produce multiple files and it doesn't seem to be executing properly - the files aren't produced. However, I don't know why this is so (python vs the sfit4 program). But because splitting the program up and running it works, I thought maybe something was wrong with the entire program.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @RandomDavis no, how would I do that? (I am new to programming)

Comment: You will have to use a Python Debugger. For example you can head over to www.jetbrains.com/pycharm and download the community edition. PyCharm is an easy to use IDE (integrated development environment). IDEs provide you the toolset to code effectively. And guess what, it also contains a debugger! :) Simply create a new file/open the existing one and set breakpoints. Breakpoints are certain lines of code where your debugger will halt and let you walk through it step by step. More info at Https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/running-and-debugging.html